# Google maps in fragment , how to display it

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to implement google maps in a fragment that is connected with the main activity, and the map with be the first view of the app. But the error below appeas when i build it.

```
Error:(166, 39) error: cannot find symbol variable MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
```

Can somebody explain  why and how can i fix please  ?
Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
    public static Tracker tracker;

    MapsFragment mapFrag;

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    private ParksFragment mParksFragment;

    MapsFragment mapFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Tracker t = ((MyApp) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.setScreenName("MainActivity");
        t.setScreenName("DetailActivity");
        t.setScreenName("MapsFragment");
        t.setScreenName("ParksFragment");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

        mapFragment = new MapsFragment();


        mParksFragment =  new ParksFragment();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);

        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new MapsFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.home_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapframe, new MapsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.parks_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ParksFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Parks");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.monuments_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new MonumentsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Monuments");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.theatrescinemas_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new TheatresFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Theatres and Cinemas");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.museums_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new MuseumsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Museums");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.festivals_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new FestivalsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Festivals and Activities");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.tips_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new TipsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Local Tips");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.settings_category:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new SettingsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                }


                return false; }
        });

    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == MapFragment.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION){
            mapFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MapsFragment:

```
public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    private final int[] MAP_TYPES = { GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE,
            GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
            GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID,
            GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN,
            GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE };
    private int curMapTypeIndex = 0;


    public MapsFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

After replacing the variable, my app got builded but it immedialely crashed. here logcat output:

```
                                                                                 --------- beginning of crash
06-20 12:47:32.999 20892-20892/com.example.user.appsightseeing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.user.appsightseeing, PID: 20892
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.appsightseeing/com.example.user.appsightseeing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.user.appsightseeing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: You attempt to use `MapFragment.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION` but your class is called `MapsFragment`?

Comment: Actually i had it HomeFragment previously .. but i got confused from some errors.. How should i change it ?

Comment: I got the issue. had misspelled the name of class. @RowlandShaw thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code

```
if (requestCode == MapsFragment.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION){
            mapFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

add this in your activity

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle ("your title" );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, but a warning says that setSupportActionBac cannot be applied in AppCompatActivity :/ @NileshRathod

Comment: paste your theme for that activity

Comment: Should i paste it inside the method? I had previosly declared Toolbar mToolbar, so i used it like this.

Comment: in your onCreate method

Comment: in my activitymain.xml do not have a theme declaredbut only these in the styles folder :

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" /> @NileshRathod

Comment: @SindiB did you solve your error

Comment: No. Not yet @NileshRathod

Comment: @SindiB paste your error here

Comment: Error:(41, 47) error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar  . Also i don t know to which theme to refer.

Comment: first declare your toolbar like this private Toolbar mToolbar; than use it

Comment: thanksss !!it worked but now i am implementing a more simple way . @NileshRathod

Comment: @SindiB most welcome